# Check if a value created_at not equal to current date exists in an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a collection of `user.paid_subscriptions` in which each subscription has attributes `created_at`(datetime) and `active`(boolean).

How can I check if a `PaidSubscription` exists such that `created_at` is **not equal** to a certain date and `active` is `true`?

`PaidSubscription` looks like this:

```
[
  #<PaidSubscription id: 11457,
    user_id: 12,
    period: 3,
    price: 4000,
    expires_at: "2016-03-08 09:44:56",
    expires_at: "2016-03-08 09:44:56",
    created_at: "2015-12-08 09:44:56",
    updated_at: "2016-03-08 23:00:09",
    active: false,
    giver_id: 20573,
    partial: false,
    remaining_days: 0>,
  #<PaidSubscription id: 13948,
    user_id: 12,
    period: 1,
    price: 1500,
    expires_at: "2016-04-11 12:07:40",
    created_at: "2016-03-11 13:07:40",
    updated_at: "2016-04-11 22:00:11",
    active: false,
    giver_id: nil,
    partial: false,
    remaining_days: 0>,
  #<PaidSubscription id: 11458....
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

If it is a query then it should be like this

```
user.paid_subscriptions.where("created_at < :date or created_at > :date and active = :active",{date: DateTime.civil(yyyy,mm,dd), active: true})
```

Or

if it is an array you can use it like below.

```
user.paid_subscriptions.any? {|ps| ps.active && ( ps.created_at.to_date < Date.civil(yyyy, mm, dd) || ps.created_at.to_date > Date.civil(yyyy, mm, dd))}
```